# Must the champion of an entire tournament beat the champion of a possible tournament among other players?

Tags: correctness-proof, game-theory

I have a list of "players" of a "tournament". Any two *adjacent* players may "compete", which results in the loser being thrown out of the tournament. Winning is not transitive. The winner of a given competition between two players is known, but the order of competitions is not. Suppose that I have some tournament of the form $p_1, p_2, p_3, ..., p_n$ and I know that $p_1$ may win the entire tournament (depending on the order of competitions). Can I show that $p_1$ must beat some possible winner of a tournament on just $p_2, p_3, ..., p_n$?

I originally came to this while proving the correctness of an algorithm to determine the list of possible winners of a general tournament, but this specific subproblem is giving me trouble.

To begin an attempt at a solution, I offer that in the contrary case, $p_1$ must *only* compete against and beat some sequence of "losers" (players who cannot win the tournament on just $p_2, ..., p_n$ no matter the order played), with no winners losing to $p_1$. This implies that at some point, a loser must defeat a winner. This may be impossible? I can't prove that, and I don't know whether that's even true.

Comment: In case it's helpful, Yuval's nice proof also works for the case where *any* pair of players (not just an adjacent pair) can compete, with only the minor changes that in the second branch of the proof, $p_2$ becomes an arbitrary $p_j$ with $j \notin \{1, i\}$, and $p_3, \dots, p_n$ becomes $\{p_2, \dots, p_n\} \setminus \{p_j\}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a proof by induction. The base case, $n = 2$, is clear.

Now consider a tournament in which $p_1$ wins. Suppose first that the first competition doesn't involve $p_1$. Let the new set of players be $p_1,P$. By induction, we know that $p_1$ must beat one of the possible winners of the tournament in $P$, say $p_i$. Since the first competition didn't involve $p_1$, $p_i$ can also win the tournament on $p_2,\ldots,p_n$, completing the proof in this case.

Suppose next that the first competition has $p_1$ beating $p_2$. Applying the induction hypothesis, we know that $p_1$ must beat one of the possible winners of the tournament in $p_3,\ldots,p_n$, say $p_i$. If $p_i$ beats $p_2$, then $p_i$ can also win the tournament on $p_2,\ldots,p_n$, and we're done. If $p_2$ beat $p_i$, then $p_2$ can win the tournament on $p_2,\ldots,p_n$, and so we're again done (since in the first competition, $p_1$ beat $p_2$).

Answer (score 2):

We are talking about **single-elimination tournament** throughout.

Here is a proof to confirm a positive answer to the question.

Let $p_1$ win an entire tournament $T$. For every other player $q$, consider its losing chain $q=l(0), l(1),l(2),\cdots, l(d_T(q))=p_1$, where player $l(i)$ loses to player $l(i+1)$ in $T$ for all $i$, $0\le i\lt d_T(q)$. We call $d_T(q)$ **the losing degree of player $q$ in $T$**.

Let $w$ be the player among champions of all possible tournaments among players other than $p_1$ such that its losing degree $d_T(w)$ is the smallest, i.e., $w$ is "the closest to win" in $T$. Suppose $w$ loses to $s$ in $T$, i.e., $d_T(s)=d_T(w)-1<d_T(w)$. If $s$ is not $p_1$, then $s$ can be the champion of a possible tournament among players other than $p_1$ as well, which contradicts the minimality of $d_T(w)$. So $s$ must be $p_1$. The proof is done.

---

> To begin an attempt at a solution, I offer that in the contrary case, $p_1$ must only compete against and beat some sequence of "losers" (players who cannot win the tournament on just $p_2,\cdots,p_n$ no matter the order played), with no winners losing to $p_1$. This implies that at some point, a loser must defeat a winner. This may be impossible? I can't prove that, and I don't know whether that's even true.

"A loser must defeat a winner" is indeed impossible. To continue your approach, you need to find and take advantage of **the extreme case** as shown in the above proof. That is, among all cases of "a loser defeat a winner", select the winner that is closest to win the entire tournament.

---

Here are several related easy exercises.

**Exercise 1.** (One minute or less) Show that $s$ can be a possible winner of a tournament among $p_2, p_3,\cdots, p_n$ indeed in the above proof.

**Exercise 2.** For each player $p$, let $d(p)$ be the smallest $d_T(p)$ among all possible tournament $T$ on all players. Call $d(p)$ the losing degree of $p$.  Show that $d(p)\ge d(q)$ if $p$ plays worse than $q$. Give an example when the equality does hold.

**Exercise 3.** Generalize the above to tournaments among the vertices of a general directed graph $G$ that has no parallel edges, whose edge $(v_i,v_j)$ means vertex $v_i$ plays worse than vertex $v_j$.